# Prncnfg.vbs Unable to get configuration for printer 0x80041002 Not Found

Tags: printing, batch-file, cmd.exe

[Print Logs](https://www.scribd.com/document/327333838/Print-Logs)

[batch file](https://www.scribd.com/document/327334114/batch-code-for-Printer)

Hi, I am currently getting the following error:

```
 Unable to get configuration for printer %remoteComputerIP%,3,Windows NT x86 Error 0x80041002 Not found 
 Operation GetObject
 Provider CIMWin32
 Description 
 Win32 error code
```

The code seems to execute. All of the code I am running remotely, and I have the proper permissions to create.

I create a port, assign a driver, set the default printer, but when it comes to configure the printer, so I can display it, it fails because it cannot find the printer object. Now, I can only see two ways this playing out:

1. The code is false positive and I am successfully creating the printer driver and port(but when i look at the other computer I do see a create port without a sharename)
2. The printer location is set incorrectly and cannot find the printer because it is looking in the wrong area.

My objective is to create a printer for a remote computer. After all the code runs, a do see a port, and a driver, however, when you go into devices and printers, only the default ones are seen. I have restarted the spool and restarted the computer.

Comment: is `%remoteComputerIP%,` actually part of the error or is this something you altered for purposes of the question?

Comment: altered for purposes of the question.

Comment: Please [edit] and include the batch file and logs **in the question**.